# Magento Footer display homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, home, footer, footer-links

I have developed magento website in version 1.9.2.4 in which footer link display in homepage only and other page footer link will hide so how can i display in another page ?

Comment: there is something wrong in page layout. which layout you are using on home and this is the default magento layout or this is the custom layout page

Comment: Try this in your local.xml <reference name="footer">
     
     <block type="cms/block" name="Name Of Footer Block">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_custom_footer</block_id></action>
     </block> 
    </reference>

Comment: I am used default/theme531 theme and in homepage i have used 1column layout and other pages two column. And where i can create local.xml

Comment: in your theme only

Comment: please share your footer code here